# Threads are slow when audio is off

Tags: c++, audio, mfc

I have 2 projects. One is built by C++ Builder without MFC Style. And other one is VC++ MFC 11.

When I create a thread and create a cycle -- let's say this cycle adds one to progressbar position -- from 1 to 100 by using `Sleep(10)` it works of course for both C++ Builder and C++ MFC.

Now, `Sleep(10)` is wait 10 miliseconds. OK. But the problem is only if I have open media player, Winamp or anything else that produces "Sound". If I close all media player, winamp and other sound programs, my threads get slower than 10 miliseconds.

It takes like `50-100 ms / each`. If I open any music, it works normally as I expected.

I have no any idea why this is happening. I first thought that I made a mistake inside MFC App but why does C++ Builder also slow down?

And yes, I am positively sure it is sound related because I even re-formated my windows, disabled everything. Lastly I discovered that sound issue.

Does my code need something?

**Update**:

<s>Now, I follow the code and found that I used `Sleep(1)` in such areas to wait 1 miliseconds. The reason of this, I move an object from left to right. If I remove this sleep then the moving is not showing up because it is very fast. So, I should use `Sleep(1)`. With `Sleep(1)`, if audio is **on** than it works. If audio is **off** than it is very slow.</s>

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
   theDialog->staticText->SetWindowsPosition(NULL, i, 20, 0, 0);
   Sleep(1);
}
```

So, suggestions regarding this are really appreciated. What should I do?

I know this is the incorrect way. I should use something else that is proper and valid. But what exactly? Which function or class help me to move static texts from one position to another smoothly?

Also, changing the thread **priority** has not helped.

**Update 2**:

Update 1 is an another question :)

Comment: Interesting.  Is the priority of your process still the same when you notice the difference?

Comment: Priorities of processes are same. The second interest thing is, if i open media player (but not play a music) my thread program runs with 2% of CPU and thread works. If i close media player, instantly slow down and it takes 0% of CPU.

Comment: This could be due to processors throttling the frequency of the cpu.

Comment: I will reset my BIOS settings but how can i make my program works as expected without changing the CPU settings from BIOS. This is ridiculous ... I have Intel i7 with X58 Chipset with 24GB of Memory. This is the first time i have ever seen such issue.

Comment: All in the name of power saving.  :-)

Comment: I am wondering if i use `SetSystemPowerState();` will this do anything? (I don't have VS IDE right now)

Comment: I am confused. Both suggested answers explain why a `Sleep(10)` might sleep longer while a high priority process is running but your problem seems to be the opposite: The `Sleep(10)` takes longer **unless** a high priority or multimedia process is running. This would rather indicate a problem with system timers. Have you updated your chipset drivers? Have you tried running the code in question on a different machine?

Comment: @Tim i digg it and found something that interesting. I updated the question.

Comment: @Unapiedra, well, sorry for my bad english. Dig maybe? Playing with code looking deeper? Following lines one-by-one :)

Comment: @xangr Ah, okay. I didn't know people say that but it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sleep (10), will (as we know), wait for approximately 10 milliseconds. If there is a higher priority thread which needs to be run at that moment, the thread wakeup maybe delayed. Multimedia threads are probably running in a Real-Time or High priority, as such when you play sound, your thread wakeup gets delayed.

Refer to Jeffrey Richters comment in Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows (4th Ed), section Sleeping in Chapter 7:

> The system makes the thread not schedulable for approximately the
>   number of milliseconds specified. That's right—if you tell the system
>   you want to sleep for 100 milliseconds, you will sleep approximately
>   that long but possibly several seconds or minutes more. Remember that
>   Windows is not a real-time operating system. Your thread will probably
>   wake up at the right time, but whether it does depends on what else is
>   going on in the system.

Also as per MSDN [Multimedia Class Scheduler Service (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

MMCSS *ensures that time-sensitive processing receives prioritized access to CPU resources.*

As per the above documentation, you can also control the percentage of CPU resources that will be guaranteed to low-priority tasks, through a registry key

Answer (score 4):

`Sleep(10)` waits for *at least* 10 milliseconds. You have to write code to check how long you actually waited and if it's more than 10 milliseconds, handle that sanely in your code. Windows is not a real time operating system.

Comment: I'm sure he's aware of this. The question is what has such a big effect on the size of a quantum or if it's just random chance. Also depending on the problem "handle it sensibly" is just out of the question (e.g. audio or video replay).

Comment: @Voo is right. I am aware of this. I will try to solve this issue by using `SetSystemPowerState()` function after i install the IDE.

Comment: @Voo: He's updating a progress bar position. Handling it sensibly is virtually trivial.

Comment: @xangr: Why do something with serious, drastic system-wide negative effects on performance when you can trivially handle this in your own code?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the progress bar code is just for an example of this issue. My real code is much more complex and different than this. The problem is, progress bar or else, it takes too much when audio is off. If audio is on and play anything my program works perfectly as i expected. Also, i am not talking about few miliseconds. It gives huge difference. (even if it has a 3 lines code :))But, if you trying to say something else that i understand wrongly, please inlight me :) Ah, also try to change thread priority too.

Comment: @David Well I assumed the "update a progressbar" was only an example, because really I doubt he'd even notice the difference if that was the only thing he was doing ;) It doesn't seem that unlikely that someone would want to do something that needs less than 100ms of quantum time - it's an interesting question and if it's just for people wanting to implement their own video/music player.

Comment: According to second answer you are half correct (i think half is the correct word). (About real time os)

Answer (score 2):

The minimum resolution for `Sleep()` timing is set system wide with `timeBeginPeriod()` and `timeEndPeriod()`.  For example passing `timeBeginPeriod(1)` sets the minimum resolution to 1 ms.  It may be that the audio programs are setting the resolution to 1 ms, and restoring it to something greater than 10 ms when they are done.  I had a problem with a program that used `Sleep(1)` that only worked fine when the XE2 IDE was running but would otherwise sleep for 12 ms.  I solved the problem by directly setting `timeBeginPeriod(1)` at the beginning of my program.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx